# Gradiente en Dreamweaver 8

Tags: dreamweaver

me gustaría saber como hago un gradiente en Macromedia Dreamweaver 8 ya que estoy aprendiendo a usar el programa. Recién estoy empezando a usarlo y no he encontrado ningún tutorial que me explique como hacerlo